# Is 'get something confused' idiomatic?

Tags: usage

If so, *'get something confusing'* must be wrong.

Do you often use *'get something confused'*?
Because when I googled, I found few examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "get something confusing", but it's possible and may not be wrong, for example:
"I get lots of messages that aren't completely clear. I got something confusing today."
That would mean that I received a message that confused me.

To "get something confused" could have two meanings.

1. As in the example above, it could mean that you received something that had been confused, or that you considered confused or unclear.
2. But the more likely meaning of "I got something confused." would be that I myself mixed something up, so my understanding was confused. For example,
   "I considered two models of car, but I got the features confused and didn't know which to buy."

Comment: Your kind explanation reminds me that "get something confusing" is also possible. Thank you.